# Encrypting URLs in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption

I'm planning to compile my application to an executable file using Py2Exe. However, I have sensitive URL links in my application that I would like to remain hidden as in encrypted. Regardless if my application is decompiled, the links will still remain encrypted. How would I get say urllib2 to open the encrypted link?

Any help would be appreciated, and or example code that could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066361/how-to-obfuscate-python-code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think urllib2 has an option like it, though what you can do is save the link somewhere else (say a simple database, encrypt them (like a password) and when urllib2 calls the link, you check the hash.

Something like an user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

URL encryption will not save you in this situation. As your software runs in the client machine and somehow decrypts this URL and sends an HTTP request to it, any kid using Wireshark will be able to see your URL.

If the design of your system requires sensitive URLs, the safer way probably involves changes in the design of your HTTP server itself! You have to structure your system in a way that the URLs are not sensitive because you cannot control them. As soon as they are used by your code, they can be captured.